# ServiceStack.SessionFeature not customizable

Tags: session, servicestack

Everything is customizable but SessionFeature (Also it is derived from IPlugin :) ) is mandatory.
I want to use MySessionFeature:IPlugin but everywhere in Controller,Attribute ... it is used as strong-typed.
Is it by-design or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SessionFeature contains useful overloads and sets the ss-id,ss-pid and ss-opts cookies on the response that are required for everything in ServiceStack that relies on the Session to work like the IAuthSession/CustomUserSession and Authentication.

You can register the Session plugin without Authentication, but when you register the Authentication plugin it will automatically register the Session Plugin if you haven't already.

Comment: Another tiny question about naming convention.Why "SessionFeature" instead of SessionPlugin?

Comment: Historic reasons, i.e. it existed before we added "Plugins" :)

Comment: So my next plugin will be named as SubscriptionPlugin :)